# When a Stack Exchange website is shut down, please notify the users who posted content on the removed website

Tags: feature-request, notifications

Feature request: When a Stack Exchange website is shut down (e.g. as a failed beta), please email users who previously posted content on the site.

Productivity.SE was closed some time ago. I [had](https://web.archive.org/web/20160711182712/http://productivity.stackexchange.com/users/2476/franck-dernoncourt) 10 questions and answers there, and I believe I should have been notified out of decency for people contributing to content.

Comment: Are you specifically asking for *email* notifications? There are other options, most notably a notification in the global SE inbox.

Comment: @bobble Good point, I think it's important enough for both global SE inbox. and email.

Comment: These are a tiny bit far from duplicates, but of note: Reminders or emails to either save or say goodbye for sites goes against an internal philosophy - that people should have worked so such a state never happens, not be told before or after (sometimes *during*, in the case of Elections):  https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360166/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215537/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/207295/282094

Comment: @Rob it's not reasonable to ask me to work to avoid the closure of the 100 SE sites where I've at least one post.

Comment: @Franck, that's not what my prior comment, or non Staff answers,  in those posts suggest. I upvoted this FR, because maybe the new company disagrees with the former methods. - Don't conflate your [click-thru on every site where you are a member](https://stackexchange.com/users/169656/franck-dernoncourt?tab=accounts) (all showing "today") and sparse actual participation on all but a few sites with what the other people say (I have no answer or comments there) at those links offered - it's what the answer from staff **might** be; and knowing what is said there provides the solution you seek.

Comment: As an aside, there's datadumps for closed sites on closure right? In theory letting a user know that/where along with the potential closure of the site feels useful should this be done.

Comment: Related: [How can we preserve Area 51 sites that get closed during the beta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359676/348196)

Comment: I disagree with the dupe closure; the dupe is about getting a notification *prior* to site closure (in an effort to save the site), this post is about getting one *after* closure. Those are arguably very distinct, and the reasons used against the former (eg. artificial inflation in traffic) would *not* apply to the latter.